# adding another module to dependencies using Kotlin dsl build script

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

in groovy build script,

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':nameless-core')
}
```

we can add another modules at same project to dependencies.
is kotlin dsl build script can?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ah!

```
dependencies {
    implementation(project(":nameless-core"))
}
```